# Positioning plots in a pdf using R

Tags: r, visualization

I have been wanting to place a plot in the top right corner of a pdf using R.

My approach has been to:

--> ***convert the plot into a png***

--> ***then insert the png into a viewport that has been placed in the top right corner of the pdf graphic device.**
*

The problem is that the graph is getting place in the top right but there is some uncanny white space strip left above the top of the viewport(that i suspect is due to some default margins of pdf.)

**Is there any better way to position my plot/s in a pdf**?

I have provided my code here :

```
librarian::shelf(magick,grid)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

png("my_new.png", width = 800, height = 800)  # Set PNG dimensions

par(
  oma = c(1.5, 2, 1.5, 2),  # Set outer margins (top, right, bottom, left)
  mar = c(3, 1, 1.5, 2),    # Set margins (bottom, left, top, right)
  mfrow = c(2, 2),          # Set the layout for multiple plots
  pch = 16,                 # Set the plotting symbol (filled circle)
  lwd = 2,                  # Set the line width
  col = "darkturquoise",    # Set the color of plotting symbols and lines
  bg = "snow",              # Set the background color
  cex.axis = 1.3,           # Set the size of axis labels and tick marks
  cex = 1.2                 # Set the overall size of text and symbols
)

# Plot 1
plot(1:10, main = "Plot 1",pch = 19, col = "darkblue", cex = 1.5)
lines(1:10, col = "red", lwd = 2)  # Add red lines

# Histogram
hist(rnorm(100), main = "Histogram",col = "skyblue")

# Barplot
barplot(table(sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE)), main = "Barplot",col = rainbow(5))

# Scatter
plot(x, y, main = "Scatterplot Example", col = rgb(0, 100, 0, 50, maxColorValue = 150))

dev.off()  # Close the PNG device


# Loading the images
image <- image_read("my_new.png")

# checking for dimensions
original_width <- image_info(image)$width
print(original_width)
original_height <- image_info(image)$height
print(original_height)


# Calculate new dimensions for 45% scaling
new_width <- original_width * 0.45
new_height <- original_height * 0.45


# Create the PDF
pdf("combined_output2.pdf", width = 8.27, height = 11.69,pin = c(plot_width, plot_height))
insert_image <- image %>%
  image_scale(paste0(new_width, "x", new_height)) %>%  # Resize the image to 50% of its original size
  image_background("white") %>%  # Set background to white (optional)
  image_ggplot()  # Convert to ggplot object

#creating a viewport to insert into the pdf graphic device.
insert_vp <- viewport(x = 1, y = 1, width = 0.4, height = 0.4, just = c("right", "top"))
pushViewport(insert_vp)
print(insert_image, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()

# Close the PDF device
dev.off()
```

Comment: It seems odd to me to try to position a plot within a pdf file when the pdf file is just the plot. That is, questions for `rmarkdown`/`knitr` often arise asking for better control over placement of an image or table, and that's "not easy" given how LaTeX does its thing. However, this question sounds like you're trying to produce a single-image `.pdf` file with intentional white space on the left and bottom. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, in a sense yes .I am trying to create a pdf in which I can place a single image in the top right corner, meaning the top right corner of my image should align with the top right corner of the pdf (intentional white space in the left and bottom). The problem is when I run this ..the image does gets placed in the extreme right but there is a strip of white space at the top...so it's not a accurate top right placement that I wish to achieve.